# why defined '__new__' and '__init__' all in a class 

Tags: python, class

i think you can defined either '`__init__`' or '`__new__`' in  a  class,but why all defined in django.utils.datastructures.py.

my code:

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print  'aaa'
    def __new__(self):
        print 'sss'

a()#print 'sss'

class b:
    def __init__(self):
        print  'aaa'
    def __new__(self):
        print 'sss'
b()#print 'aaa'
```

datastructures.py:

```
class SortedDict(dict):
    """
    A dictionary that keeps its keys in the order in which they're inserted.
    """
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(SortedDict, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        instance.keyOrder = []
        return instance

    def __init__(self, data=None):
        if data is None:
            data = {}
        super(SortedDict, self).__init__(data)
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            self.keyOrder = data.keys()
        else:
            self.keyOrder = []
            for key, value in data:
                if key not in self.keyOrder:
                    self.keyOrder.append(key)
```

and what circumstances the `SortedDict.__init__` will be call.

thanks

Comment: **do** read docs, they're exhaustive!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can define either or both of `__new__` and `__init__`.

`__new__` must return an object -- which can be a new one (typically that task is delegated to `type.__new__`), an existing one (to implement singletons, "recycle" instances from a pool, and so on), or even one that's *not* an instance of the class.  If `__new__` returns an instance of the class (new or existing), `__init__` then gets called on it; if `__new__` returns an object that's **not** an instance of the class, then `__init__` is *not* called.

`__init__` is passed a class instance as its first item (in the same state `__new__` returned it, i.e., typically "empty") and must alter it as needed to make it ready for use (most often by adding attributes).

In general it's best to use `__init__` for all it can do -- and `__new__`, if something is left that `__init__` can't do, for that "extra something".

So you'll typically define both if there's something useful you can do in `__init__`, but not everything you want to happen when the class gets instantiated.

For example, consider a class that subclasses `int` but also has a `foo` slot -- and you want it to be instantiated with an initializer for the `int` and one for the `.foo`.  As `int` is immutable, that part has to happen in `__new__`, so pedantically one could code:

```
>>> class x(int):
...   def __new__(cls, i, foo):
...     self = int.__new__(cls, i)
...     return self
...   def __init__(self, i, foo):
...     self.foo = foo
...   __slots__ = 'foo',
... 
>>> a = x(23, 'bah')
>>> print a
23
>>> print a.foo
bah
>>>
```

In practice, for a case this simple, nobody would mind if you lost the `__init__` and just moved the `self.foo = foo` to `__new__`.  But if initialization is rich and complex enough to be best placed in `__init__`, this idea is worth keeping in mind.

Comment: I asked a question about inheriting multiple classes dynamically yesterday. Based on your current example I did this: http://gist.github.com/271098
Whats wrong?

Comment: Alex, could you please explain why `__new__` is overriden in the particular case of SortedDict implementation? What's so bad about initializing the `keyOrder` attribute in the `__init__`? The only real reason I can think of is, that it is done to ensure, that the attribute gets created even if SortedDict is subclassed and the subclass doesn't call base class' `__init__`. But then again, you can do the same with `__new__`, right?

Comment: @becomingGuru, many bugs in that code, but the first one is that you're using old-style classes: don't -- always use new-style ones (inherit from `object`). In this case this will reveal the second bug, once fixed you'll have a third one, etc. Why not open a SO question and ask to get your code debugged, there's way too many bugs in your code to explain them all in a comment!

Comment: @shylent, bypassing a superclass's `__new__` requires malice aforethought (as you're always delegating to _some_ ancestor `__new__`, skipping the superclass must be explicit), while bypassing `__init__` requires a mere sin of omission. But yes, that code's any use only if in some case that `__init__` is not called (or some subclass does some things between the `__new__` and the call to `__init__`) -- the class itself as coded has no need for that `__new__`.

Comment: Alex; Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026572/python-multiple-inheritance-whats-wrong-doing-it-dynamically

Answer (score 9):

`__new__` and `__init__` do completely different things. The method `__init__` initiates a new instance of a class --- it is a constructor. `__new__` is a far more subtle thing --- it can change arguments and, in fact, the class of the initiated object. For example, the following code:

```
class Meters(object):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        return int(value / 3.28083)
```

If you call `Meters(6)` you will not actually create an instance of `Meters`, but an instance of `int`. You might wonder why this is useful; it is actually crucial to metaclasses, an admittedly obscure (but powerful) feature.

You'll note that in Python 2.x, only classes inheriting from `object` can take advantage of `__new__`, as you code above shows.

The use of `__new__` you showed in django seems to be an attempt to keep a sane method resolution order on `SortedDict` objects. I will admit, though, that it is often hard to tell why `__new__` is necessary. Standard Python style suggests that it not be used unless necessary (as always, better class design is the tool you turn to first).

Comment: `__new__` is THE constructor, `__init__` is ...just init-ialization

Comment: @Anurag: Pedantically speaking, you are correct. Though, if you're coming from a language other than Python, it's best to be told that `__init__` is the constructor --- people are good enough at abusing features without my help. So, I'm keeping `__init__` as constructor in my response for the benefit of possible others.

Answer (score 2):

My only guess is that in this case, they (author of this class) want the keyOrder list to exist on the class even before `SortedDict.__init__` is called.

Note that SortedDict calls `super()` in its `__init__`, this would ordinarily go to `dict.__init__`, which would probably call `__setitem__` and the like to start adding items. `SortedDict.__setitem__` expects the `.keyOrder` property to exist, and therein lies the problem (since `.keyOrder` isn't normally created until after the call to `super()`.)  It's possible this is just an issue with subclassing `dict` because my normal gut instinct would be to just initialize `.keyOrder` before the call to `super()`.

The code in `__new__` might also be used to allow SortedDict to be subclassed in a diamond inheritance structure where it is possible `SortedDict.__init__` is not called before the first `__setitem__` and the like are called.  Django has to contend with various issues in supporting a wide range of python versions from 2.3 up; it's possible this code is completely un-neccesary in some versions and needed in others.

---

There is a common use for defining both `__new__` and `__init__`: accessing class properties which may be eclipsed by their instance versions without having to do `type(self)` or `self.__class__` (which, in the existence of metaclasses, may not even be the right thing).

For example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    creation_counter = 0

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.creation_counter += 1
        return super(MyClass, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self):
         print "I am the %dth myclass to be created!" % self.creation_counter
```

Finally, `__new__` can actually return an instance of a wrapper or a completely different class from what you thought you were instantiating. This is used to provide metaclass-like features without actually needing a metaclass.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there was no need of overriding `__new__` in the example you described.
Creation of an instance and actual memory allocation happens in `__new__`, `__init__` is called after `__new__` and is meant for initialization of instance serving the job of constructor in classical OOP terms. So, if all you want to do is initialize variables, then you should go for overriding `__init__`. 
The real role of `__new__` comes into place when you are using Metaclasses. There if you want to do something like changing attributes or adding attributes, that must happen before the creation of class, you should go for overriding `__new__`.

Consider, a completely hypothetical case where you want to make some attributes of class private, even though they are not defined so (I'm not saying one should ever do that).

```
class PrivateMetaClass(type):
      def __new__(metaclass, classname, bases, attrs):
          private_attributes = ['name', 'age']

          for private_attribute in private_attributes:
              if attrs.get(private_attribute):
                 attrs['_' + private_attribute] = attrs[private_attribute]
                 attrs.pop(private_attribute)

          return super(PrivateMetaClass, metaclass).__new__(metaclass, classname, bases, attrs)


class Person(object):

      __metaclass__ = PrivateMetaClass

      name = 'Someone'
      age = 19

person = Person()
>>> hasattr(person, 'name')
False
>>> person._name
'Someone'
```

Again, It's just for instructional purposes I'm not suggesting one should do anything like this.