# Python multiple inheritance: Whats wrong doing it dynamically?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017876/why-defined-new-and-init-all-in-a-class/2017980#2017980), of how `__new__` and `__init__` are supposed to work in Python,

I wrote this code to dynamically define and create a new class and object.

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls):
      class C(cls, B):
          pass
      self = C()
      return self

    def foo(self):
      print 'foo'

class B(object):
    def bar(self):
      print 'bar'

a = A()
a.foo()
a.bar()
```

Basically, because the `__new__` of A returns a dynamically created C that inherits A and B, it should have an attribute `bar`.

Why does `C` *not* have a `bar` attribute?

Comment: Based on what answer? Are you missing a link?

Comment: Roger, Dominic, Yup the link was missing. Now updated the question, appropriately.

Comment: Still don't see a question.  If there's an error message you don't understand, include the error message (and traceback if it's an exception).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Resolve](http://codepad.org/PhYOUqxc) the infinite recursion:

```
class A(object):
  def __new__(cls):
    class C(cls, B):
      pass
    self = object.__new__(C)
    return self
```

(Thanks to [balpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026572/python-multiple-inheritance-whats-wrong-doing-it-dynamically/2026633#2026633) for pointing out the actual question.)

Answer (score 7):

Since there is no actual *question* in the *question*, I am going to take it literally:

**Whats wrong doing it dynamically?**
Well, it is practically unreadable, extremely opaque and non-obvious to the user of your code (that includes you in a month :P).

From my experience (quite limited, I must admit, unfortunately I don't have 20 years of programming under the belt), a need for such solutions indicates, that the class structure is not well defined, - means, there's almost always a better, more readable and less arcane way to do such things.

For example, if you **really** want to define base classes on the fly, you are better off using a factory function, that will return appropriate classes according to your needs.

Another take on the question:
**Whats wrong doing it dynamically?**
In your current implementation, it gives me a "maximum recursion depth exceeded" error. That happens, because `A.__new__` calls itself from within itself indefinitely (since it inherits from itself and from `B`).

**10:** Inside `A.__new__`, "cls" is set to `<class '.A'>`. Inside the constructor you define a class `C`, which inherits from `cls` (which is actually `A`) and another class `B`. Upon instantiating `C`, its `__new__` is called. Since it doesn't define its own `__new__`, its base class' `__new__` is called. The base class just happens to be `A`.
**20: GOTO 10**

Answer (score 3):

If your question is "How can I accomplish this" – this works:

```
class A(object):
    @classmethod
    def get_with_B(cls):
      class C(B, cls):
        pass

      return C()

    def foo(self):
      print 'foo'

class B(object):
    def bar(self):
      print 'bar'

a = A.get_with_B()
a.foo()
a.bar()
```

If your question is "Why doesn't it work" – that's because you run into an infinite recursion when you call `C()`, which leads to `A.__new__` being called, which again calls `C()` etc.