# Python: always use __new__ instead of __init__?

Tags: python, new-style-class

I understand how both `__init__` and `__new__` work.
I'm wondering if there is anything `__init__` can do that `__new__` cannot?

i.e. can use of `__init__` be replaced by the following pattern:

```
class MySubclass(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        self = super(MySubclass, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        // Do __init__ stuff here
        return self
```

I'm asking as I'd like to make this aspect of Python OO fit better in my head.

Comment: Old question on that topic: [Python’s use of \_\_new__ and \_\_init__ ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init)

Comment: possible duplicate of [why defined '\_\_new__' and '\_\_init__' all in a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017876/why-defined-new-and-init-all-in-a-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible answer from [guido's post](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/inside-story-on-new-style-classes.html) (thanks @fraca7):

> For example, in the pickle module, `__new__` is used to create instances when unserializing objects. In this case, instances are created, but the `__init__` method is not invoked.

Any other similar answers?

---

I'm accepting this answer as a 'yes' to my own question:

> I'm wondering if there is anything `__init__` can do that `__new__` cannot?

Yes, unlike `__new__`, actions that you put in the `__init__` method will not be performed during the unpickling process.  `__new__` cannot make this distinction.

Answer (score 24):

So, the class of a class is typically `type`, and when you call `Class()` the `__call__()` method on `Class`'s class handles that. I believe `type.__call__()` is implemented more or less like this:

```
def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    # should do the same thing as type.__call__
    obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    if isinstance(obj, cls):
        obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    return obj
```

The direct answer to your question is no, the things that `__init__()` can do (change / "initialize" a specified instance) is a subset of the things that `__new__()` can do (create or otherwise select whatever object it wants, do anything to that object it wants before the object is returned).

It's convenient to have both methods to use, however. The use of `__init__()` is simpler (it doesn't have to create anything, it doesn't have to return anything), and I believe it is best practice to always use `__init__()` unless you have a specific reason to use `__new__()`.

Comment: To me, this doesn't really answer the OP's question. You said that "the things that `__init__()` can do is a subset of the things that `__new__()` can do", but that's precisely the OP's point, isn't it? If that sentence is true, then `__init__()` can be safely deprecated, because anything it can do, `__new__()` can do just as well.

Comment: @Ray **Your conclusion fails to follow from your premise.** While that sentence *is* ostensibly true, `__init__()` cannot be safely deprecated for all of the obvious reasons – notably, **(A)** the need to preserve backward compatibility with the existing Python ecosystem *and* **(B)** the contractual fragility of the `__new__()` API (whose design mandates that an instance be explicitly returned) versus the `__init__()` API (whose design imposes no such constraints). `__new__()` invites API violations, which is bad; `__init__()` does *not*, which is good.

Answer (score 2):

Well, looking for `__new__ vs __init__` on google showed me [this](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2008-April/061426.html).

Long story short, `__new__` returns a new object instance, while `__init__` returns nothing and just initializes class members.

EDIT: To actually answer your question, you should never need to override `__new__` unless you are subclassing immutable types.

Comment: Guido talked about that recently:

http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/inside-story-on-new-style-classes.html

Comment: There are other reasons to use `__new__`,for example the flyweight pattern.