# Why not just __new__ and not __new__ and __init__ in python?

Tags: python

Assume the following code:

```
class NumStorage(object):

    def __new__(cls, *nargs):
        name = cls.__name__
        parents = cls.__bases__
        kwargs = {'num%i' % pos : i for pos, i in enumerate(nargs, 1)}
        if any(kwargs.values()) and len(kwargs.values()) >= 2:
            end = len(kwargs.values()) + 1
            kwargs['num%i' % end] = sum(kwargs.values())
        self = type(name, parents, kwargs)
        return self
```

This `NumStorage` object takes in an arbitrary amount of numbers, and if there are two or more numbers and their sum adds up to something greater than 0, then it creates a new `kwarg` key.

If the initialization of the instance of NumStorage can happen in `__new__` then why on earth does python even *need* an `__init__`? Another thing that's confusing me; if we do add an `__init__` method to the `NumStorage` class as so:

```
class NumStorage(object):

    def __new__(cls, *nargs):
        name = cls.__name__
        parents = cls.__bases__
        kwargs = {'num%i' % pos : i for pos, i in enumerate(nargs, 1)}
        if any(kwargs.values()) and len(kwargs.values()) >= 2:
            end = len(kwargs.values()) + 1
            kwargs['num%i' % end] = sum(kwargs.values())
        self = type(name, parents, kwargs)
        return self

    def __init__(self, *nargs):
        print("initializing")
```

It never prints "initializing" even though the `__init__` should be called after `__new__` since `__new__` returned an instance of the object, no? If not, what is it I'm getting confused with?

Comment: Does any of those answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/3131488/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4859129/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8609153/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/674304/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/9367126/218196

Comment: Thanks for supplying those resources! I looked through a lot of stuff before posting this question but never came across those questions and they cleared up a lot of my confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__init__` came first. `__new__` was added primarily to... well, I'll let the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) explain:

> `__new__()` is intended mainly to allow subclasses of immutable types (like int, str, or tuple) to customize instance creation. It is also commonly overridden in custom metaclasses in order to customize class creation.

`__init__` was mostly good enough for the old-style class system. Even if you subclassed an "immutable" old-style class, you'd just provide the appropriate arguments to the superclass's `__init__`. That doesn't cut it with subclasses of, say, `tuple`.

As for `__init__` not being called:

> If `__new__()` returns an instance of *cls*, then the new instance’s
>   `__init__()` method will be invoked like `__init__(self[, ...])`, where *self* is the new instance and the remaining arguments are the same as
>   were passed to `__new__()`.
>
> If `__new__()` does not return an instance of *cls*, then the new
>   instance’s `__init__()` method will not be invoked.

Comment: Then how may I edit the above code so that `__new__` returns an instance of the class `NumStorage`, since I thought using type would be the way to do it?

Comment: @user3002473: What you're doing with `type` is creating and returning a new class. Instead, what you need to do is call `super(NumStorage, cls).__new__(cls, *nargs)` and then do whatever you need to initialize the object.

Comment: Ahh that makes a lot of sense now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

> does python even *need* an `__init__`?

No, python doesn't *need* `__init__`, but if there were only `__new__`, every time you created a class, you'd need to figure out all the bits and pieces that go into `__new__`.

It makes python much easier, and less error prone, to separate the two out.

Plus, historically `__init__` precedes `__new__`.