# What can `__init__` do that `__new__` cannot?

Tags: python, initialization

In Python, `__new__` is used to initialize immutable types and `__init__` typically initializes mutable types.  If `__init__` were removed from the language, what could no longer be done (easily)?

For example,

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, *, x, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x = x


class B(A):

    def __init__(self, y=2, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.y = y
```

Could be rewritten using `__new__` like this:

```
class A_N:

    def __new__(cls, *, x, **kwargs):
        obj = super().__new__(cls, **kwargs)
        obj.x = x
        return obj


class B_N(A_N):

    def __new__(cls, y=2, **kwargs):
        obj = super().__new__(cls, **kwargs)
        obj.y = y
        return obj
```

---

Clarification for scope of question:  This is not a question about how `__init__` and `__new__` are used or what is the difference between them.  This is a question about what would happen if `__init__` were removed from the language.  Would anything break?  Would anything become a lot harder or impossible to do?

Comment: @matino *were* is the subjunctive;  *was* is the indicative.

Comment: Not quite. `__new__` is the constructor, `__init__` is the initializer. However, (from [Python's use of `__new__` and `__init__`?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/674369/4014959) ) "In general, you shouldn't need to override `__new__` unless you're subclassing an immutable type like `str`, `int`, `unicode` or `tuple`". Sure, you _can_ initialize stuff via `__new__`, but that's not the conventional Python style, and  most experienced Python coders will assume you're doing something special if you override `__new__`. IOW, it's really a matter of style and language design.

Comment: You can do everything with `__new__`, but this might introduce many bugs for many reasons.

Comment: @MokonaModoki It's not a duplicate.  Did you read my clarification?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131488/python-always-use-new-instead-of-init

Comment: @PM2Ring: "`__new__` is the constructor, `__init__` is the initializer" - why do people keep saying this? In what bizarre definition is `__init__` not a constructor? It takes an allocated, uninitialized object and brings it into an initialized, usable state. This is what constructors do in pretty much every language that has constructors. I'm not aware of any definition under which the constructor is responsible for allocation like `__new__`. Python has its weird allocator/secondary constructor thing in `__new__` because it turned out the first constructor design wasn't quite flexible enough.

Comment: @user2357112: I guess people keep saying that because `__new__` returns an instance and `__init__` initializes it, and it's convenient to have a clear way to distinguish between these two processes. True,  `__new__` can do initialization, and it may return an existing instance rather than allocating a fresh one (but when that happens `__init__` isn't automatically invoked). But `__init__` shouldn't create an instance: it expects to be passed an instance that it can initialize. If you wish to refer to both of these methods as constructors, feel free, but that's not the usual Python convention.

Comment: @PM2Ring  Do you have a source that it is the usual Python convention to call one the constructor and the other the initializer?

Comment: @NeilG: How about this quote from [Dive into Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6578487/4014959)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything you can do in `__init__` can also be done in `__new__`.

Then, why use `__init__`?
Because you don't have to store instance in variable (`obj` in your example code), and later bother returning it. You can focus on what you realy want to do – initializing mutable object.

Comment: I'm going to wait at least day before accepting this since I'm still not sure!

Answer (score 20):

### Note about difference between __new__ and __init__

Before explaining missing functionality let's get back to definition of `__new__` and `__init__`:

**__new__** is the first step of instance creation. It's called first, and is **responsible for returning a new instance** of your class.

However, **__init__ doesn't return anything**; it's only responsible for
initializing the instance after it's been created.

### Consequences of replacing __init__ with __new__

Mainly you would lose out on flexibility. You would get a lot of semantics headaches and loose separation of initializatin and construction (by joining `__new__ and`**init** we are to joining construction  and initialization into one step...).
Let's take a look on snippet below:

```
class A(object):
    some_property = 'some_value'

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        obj.some_property = cls.some_property
        return obj


class B(A):
    some_property = 2

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(B, cls).__new__(cls)
        return obj
```

Consequences of moving `__init__` actions into `__new__`:

1. Initialize `B` before `A`: When you are using `__new__` method instead of `__init__` your first step of creating new instance of B is calling `A.__new__` as side effect you cannot initialize `B` before `A` is initialized ( access and assign some properties to new B instance). Using of **`__init__`** gives you such flexability.
2. Loose control on initializing order: let's imagine that you have `B_N` inherited from two classes (`A_N1`, `A_N2`), now you would miss controlling of order of initializing new instance of `B_N`(what is the order you are going to initialize instances ? it could be matter... what is weird.)
3. Properties and methods mess: you would miss access to `A.some_property` (`cls` would be equal to `B` while instantiating new instance of `B`. However directly accessing of `A.some_property` is possible, but my guess it's at least weird to access properties within class throught class name and not by using `classmethods`).
4. You cannot re-initialize an existed instance without creating new one or implementation special logic for this ( thanks to **@platinhom** for idea )

### What can `__init__` do that `__new__` cannot?

There are no actions that cannot be done in `__new__` and can in `__init__`, because  actions that `__init__` performs **is a subset** of the actions that can be performed by `__new__`.

An interesting moment from [Python  Docs, Pickling and unpickling normal class instances#object.**getinitargs**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getinitargs__) regarding when `__init__` could be usefull:

> When a pickled class instance is unpickled, its **init**() method is normally not invoked.

Comment: I know what they do, but this doesn't anwer my question at all.

Comment: Did you see my updated question?  That's exactly what I do.

Comment: Yes, but you can manipulate the instance of `B`.  I show you how to do that in my updated question.  You must call `super` by the way.   You can't call `object.__new__` from `B` and you probably should get into the habit of calling it from `A`'s `__new__` as well.

Comment: 1. A's `__new__` will create an instance of B if `cls=B`. 2. The order is the inheritance order just like with `__init__`. 3. You can access the properties through the created object that is passed.

Comment: I will also use `__init__` as a `reset` function. Can `__new__` do it without creating a new method ?

Comment: @platinhom thanks for idea, yes that's not possible until you add some special login to `\__new__`

Comment: Good answer! You could probably focus the points 1 and 3 some more. - You simply cannot initialize B (or set any value on the object) before A is initialized if you have only `__new__`. And it is a bit troublesome to call member functions inside of `__new__`

Comment: Why would you not be able to access `A.some_property`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  You can.  This answer is almost totally wrong.

Comment: @NeilG,  I have to say I was thinking the same, I am amazed at how many upvotes this has gotten.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham and NeilG.
My guess is that answer looks weird for you due to concentrating on opinion that  "it's not a problem of mixing construction  and  initialization of new instance, we would always find workaround" while my answer attempts to highlight  inconveniences,confusing moments and obscure commands execution which became routine part of development after mixing init and new due to loosing flow controlling ( separation of construction and initialization of new instances) .

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko Your answer is not "weird" and you still refuse to address my responses.  Your points #2 (you can't control it with `__init__` either) and #3 (see my question) are wrong, and point #4 is a bad idea (nowhere in Python do you use `__init__` as a substitute for `clear` and I think this is a bad idea in general.)  Point #1 is a valid, if limited, point.  It should be your entire answer in my opinion.

Comment: In fact, your point #3 shows a total misunderstanding of how inheritance works in Python.  Even if `cls` is `B`, you can still access the properties of `A` since the `__mro__` will already be initialized.

Comment: #2 you cannot control initializing order: how would you initialize B then A_N2 and then A_N1 within `__new__` of B ? ( what wrong here.. ?! )

#3: I've pointed to moment that you can access class via A attributes, which is bad idea, because  you would face moment when  you need to access some props with `cls` and some with `A`, so  how such code would be supported in further development by other devs (they would be confused),  ?

#4 that's you opinion regarding re-initialization of class.

Comment: You cannot control initialization order with `__init__` either.  Note that it's wrong to call superclass `__init__` directly — you must call them through `super()`.

Comment: "You cannot control initialization ord" .... sure that should be called with super, each time when i mention about initialization order i mean calling init with super()

Comment: #3 is just wrong.  You can access parent class members just fine and it's very common to do so.  You can find  subclasses that do that in the standard library itself.

Comment: #4 is not "just my opinion".  You can see evidence of that for yourself in all of the library classes that define their own `clear` method.  You don't call `__init__` to clear a list or set or a dict.  You call `clear`.  That's pretty standard.  Suggesting that it's a good idea to manually call init is a bad idea for another reason besides just convention:  Calling magic methods breaks `__getattribute__`.

Comment: #3 just rephrase: "It's ok to access class within classmethod not as parameter because class method could be called with another context", my guess is that working flow of classmethods assume work with `cls` and accessing props via `A.prop` is ok for `staticmethods`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you're saying.  If you really believe in this answer, why don't you erase the intro and produce some examples for each of  your points?

Comment: That's list mainly rely on semantic difference and obscur actions after joining of init and highlight  moments which would be weird at least from my point of view. I don't mind to write use cases but i think they would be obscure, because there no use cases when we face wall due to not using init, there only semantic difference +  not desired initialization.

Answer (score 3):

Per [`When to use __new__ vs. __init__`](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2008-April/061426.html)

> `__new__` is the first step of instance creation.  It's called first,
>   and is responsible for returning a new instance of your class.  In
>   contrast, `__init__` doesn't return anything; it's only responsible for
>   initializing the instance after it's been created.

Also the class of class is `type`, and `type.__call__()` is implemented something like below refer to the above description:

```
def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    if isinstance(obj, cls):
        obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    return obj
```

We know `__init__()` just do a part of `__new__()` can do anything to that object before the object is returned.

> In general, you shouldn't need to override `__new__` unless you're subclassing an immutable type like str, int, unicode or tuple.

So it is not good to remove `__init__` from the language, and it is better to always use `__init__()` better than using `__new__()`.

Here is one history of [`Low-level constructors and __new__()`](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/inside-story-on-new-style-classes.html).

Comment: Okay, so the only advantage of `__init__` is the convenience of not returning the constructed object?

Comment: @NeilG: Yes, and not having to store instance in variable.