# __new__ and __init__

Tags: python

I know that `__new__`  is used to create an object, while `__init__` to initialize. But I'm don't understand how to use them, and I'm not sure what happens when I create an object. Does it mean that `__new__` and `__init__` must have the same parameters? What happens if I don't use the same parameters?

Comment: Partly answered by [why defined '\_\_new__' and '\_\_init__' all in a class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2017876)

Comment: `__new__` and `__init__` do different things and have different parameters. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674304/pythons-use-of-new-and-init) gives a good overview.

Answer (score 10):

1. Yes.
2. You will get an error.

(Technically with `__new__` the first argument is the class, while with `__init__` the first argument is the instance.  However, it is still true that they must both be able to accept the same arguments, since, except for that first argument, the arguments passed to `__init__` are the same as those passed to `__new__`.)

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __new__(cls, x):
...         return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls)
...     
...     def __init__(self, x, y):
...         pass
>>> Foo(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#260>", line 1, in <module>
    Foo(1)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
>>> Foo(1, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#261>", line 1, in <module>
    Foo(1, 2)
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: And what about `*args` and `**kw` then? Also, by passing the `x` argument on to `super(..).__new__` you are triggering a DeprecationWarning, confusing the OP.

Comment: That's why I said "must both be able to accept the same arguments".  It's true that you can use `*args` and `**kwargs` to not have the exact same argument list, but that's true for any function.  The important point is that the same args are *passed* to both functions, so they have to be able to accept the same things.  (Thanks for noting the DeprecationWarning thing, I fixed that.)

Answer (score 7):

Both methods will be passed (almost) the same set of arguments, so usually they have matching signatures (the same set of parameters).

I say 'almost' there, because the `__new__` method is passed the class as first argument, while the `__init__` method is passed the result of the `__new__` method; the freshly created instance.

In python, you *can* use "wildcard" parameters; the `*args` and `**keyword` (see [What do *args and **kwargs mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/287085)), which means that either `__new__` or `__init__` could use these to only name *some* of the parameters passed in.

What happens when the signatures don't match (taking into account the wildcard parameters)? You get the same result as passing arguments to any python callable whose signature does not match the arguments passed in; you get an exception.